# How to build measure on query field in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have a query that extracts data from an SQL database by using direct SQL statement like

SELECT Product, Quantity, Amount FROM Sales;

I need to build a measure that calculates Quantity * Amount, but when I try typing it in, it does not allow me to use fields from the query. Is this not possible in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a calculated column, not a Measure. Use the Power Query with the SQL statement to load the column for Product, Quantity and Amount. In the Query Editor add a custom column with the formula

```
=[Quantity]*[Amount]
```

Then use a measure to total that calculated column and when you use the measure in a pivot or another Power BI visualisation, it will show only the results for the values that are included in the current filter.

Comment: OK. Thanks @teylyn!

Comment: I will.
After making a new column in the editor, I still can not use that column in a measure though.

Comment: OK, I was trying to simply reverse field's sign by putting Discount = -[Amount]. This doesn't work. But Discount = -sum([Amount]) works fine. Thank you.